# How to prove spectral radius of $A-A^{\infty}$ is less than 1? $A$ is semi convergent

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrix-analysis

Suppose that $A$ is a semi-convergent matrix. Denote the limiting matrix as $A^{\infty}$. Can someone tell me, why the spectral radius of ($A-A^{\infty}$) is less than 1? I guess it is because $A-A^{\infty}$ is a convergent matrix (hence its spectral radius is less than 1). But how to prove $A-A^{\infty}$ is a convergent matrix? OR is $\rho(A-A^{\infty})<1$ a part of the implication of the-semi-convergence of $A$?

Comment: I think there is nothing to do with primitive matrix. Note that $A-A^\infty=A(I-A^\infty)$.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing to do with primitive A. So how do I compute the spectral radius of $A-A^{\infty}$ from $A-A^{\infty}=A(I-A^{\infty})$?

Comment: I think there is nothing to do with primitive matrix. Note that $A-A^\infty=A(I-A^\infty)$. If $(A-A^\infty)y=\rho y$, we'll have $A(I-A)y=A(I-A)(I-A^\infty)y=(I-A)\rho y$,which indicates $(I-A)y$ is $0$ or another eigen vector for $A$, and in the former case $(I-A^\infty)y=0$. In the latter case, for the existence of $A^\infty$, $\rho<1$.

Comment: With Jordan standard form for matrix, it would be easier to consider.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea Why is $A(I-A)y$ equal to $A(I-A)(I-A^\infty)y$?

Comment: $AA^\infty=A^\infty$, hence $(I-A)(I-A^\infty)=I-A$.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get it, can you elaborate your sentence "in the latter case, for the existence of $A^{\infty}$, $\rho<1$"?

Comment: Here is one approach to your problem. Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. The eigenvalues of $A-A^\infty$ are then $\mu_i=\lambda_i-\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda_i^k$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. (If you don't see this, turn $A$ into an upper triangular matrix by unitary triangularisation.) As $\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda_i^k$ exists, either $\lambda_i=1$ or $|\lambda_i|<1$. The rest should be straightforward.

Comment: Because of $A^\infty y=\rho^\infty y=0$.

Comment: Thanks all. I appreciate it!

Comment: Some suggestions to improve the wording of the body of your Question.  You begin by supposing "that $A$ is primitive ($\rho(A)=1$)", which makes it seem you think spectral norm $1$ is the definition of primitive.  The word "matrix" is omitted but could be inferred from the end of the sentence.  Explicit use of the word "matrix" would help to set up the problem more cleanly.

Comment: No, I did not imply that the definition of norm 1 is primitive. I will modify it though, Thanks.